# Is it possible to free target and shoot your weapon?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

In the original X-Com you could basically point your weapon any direction and fire it. You could shoot buildings, vegetation, and even your own men. If you had a strong enough weapon you could shoot through a wall and create an entry into a structure where there wasn't one before. You could also fire in the direction of enemies that you couldn't necessarily see, but which other squad members could see.

The only weapon I've had so far that is free target is the rocket launcher. I'm sorely missing the ability to fire at will. I notice that plasma and laser weapons will destroy walls and cover, but I don't can't seem to be able to fire at anything I want.

For information purposes I'm playing NORMAL: Tutorial mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, unfortunately.  The devs said it wasn't possible with the engine back before the game was released.

Comment: that and not having the ability to drop and pick up stuff (and carry more ammo such as rockets) are my biggest gripes about the game.

Comment: @yx. Same here. Free targeting is incredibly useful, and so is customizing the inventory.

Comment: I miss those things very much.  EU is a very good game in it's own right, but it's missing some of what Made the original game such a classic.  Also, the current loadout management UI is not an improvement IMO.

Comment: I would agree with the opinions here, but you have to notice that the enemy doesn't get that either.  Mutons only have one grenade and most everything else doesn't have explosives period.  If they did, they should be able to stock up too.  Honestly, though, I've found that the explosive weapons are only really good for AOE damage on small targets and destroying cover.  My laser and plasma rifles have much more punch then a rocket, and my snipers usually down end-game enemies in two shots. (Thank you, Double Tap)

Comment: @CrystalBlue there's a replacement for the rocket launcher that does 9 damage (18 damage on robots with HEAT ammo, oh my), but it is only available very late game.